# Knockout computed column with model

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have a model with the following property in my MVC C# solution

```
public class RegistrationRequirementModel
{
    public string LoadIntent { get; set; }
    public string Francophone { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public RegistrationRequirementModel(L09RegistrationRequirement requirement)
    {
        LoadIntent = requirement.LoadIntent;
        Francophone = requirement.Francophone;
        Gender = requirement.Gender;
    }
}
```

In my javascript I can call the model and display the data, however when it comes to using some computed function that is where it fails.

Javascript

```
    var registrationRequirementModel = {
        frenchData:  ko.observable(""),
        genderData:  ko.observable(""),
        loadIntentData:  ko.observable(""),

        isMissingData: ko.computed(function () {
            if (this.frenchData() == "") { return true };
            if (this.genderData() == "") { return true };
            if (this.loadIntentData() == "") { return true };
            return false;
        },this),

    }

   $(document).ready(function () {

        ko.applyBindings(registrationRequirementModel, document.getElementById("RegistrationSurveyContent"));

        $.ajax({
            url: getStudentRegRequirementsUrl,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: jsonContentType,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (!account.handleInvalidSessionResponse(data)) {
                    registrationRequirementModel.frenchData(data.Francophone);
                    registrationRequirementModel.genderData(data.Gender);
                    registrationRequirementModel.loadIntentData(data.LoadIntent);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status != 0)
                    $('#notificationHost').notificationCenter('addNotification', { message: "Unable to retrieve registration requirement.", type: "error" });
            }
        });
    });
```

Html

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: loadIntentData"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: frenchData"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: genderData"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The purpose is to show html if there is missing data. However when I activate this code, the computed column keep saying the frenchData is not a function. My point would be able to use in my html `data-bind="visible: isMissingData"`. but unfortunately. I can event read from my data.

This is my call to the api

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetRegistrationRequirementAsync()
 {
     string StudentID = CurrentUser.PersonId;
     try
     {
         var requirement = await ServiceClient.L09GetRegistrationRequirementAsync(StudentID);
         RegistrationRequirementModel registrationRequirementModel = new RegistrationRequirementModel(requirement);
         return Json(registrationRequirementModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frenchData is not a function` console error stems from the way that the KnockoutJS ViewModel is set up. In essence, the computed function `isMissingData` below the normal observables has a new inner scope context of `this` that does not reflect the same outer scope of the `registrationRequirementModel` object.

[image]

To work around this, you should switch from using an `object literal` to a `constructor function` so that you can assign `this` ViewModel scope to a `self/that` variable which alleviates scope issues. Then instantiate your newly stored ViewModel via KO Apply Bindings that you will now have access to after AJAX success:

```
function registrationRequirementModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.frenchData = ko.observable("");
  self.genderData = ko.observable("");
  self.loadIntentData = ko.observable("");

  self.isMissingData = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.frenchData() == "") {
      return true
    };
    if (self.genderData() == "") {
      return true
    };
    if (self.loadIntentData() == "") {
      return true
    };
    return false;
  }, this);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var vm = new registrationRequirementModel();
  ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("RegistrationSurveyContent"));

  // replace with endpoint
  var jsonData = {
    Francophone: "Francophone",
    Gender: "Male",
    LoadIntent: "LoadIntent"
  };

  if (handleInvalidSessionResponse(jsonData)) {
    vm.frenchData(jsonData.Francophone);
    vm.genderData(jsonData.Gender);
    vm.loadIntentData(jsonData.LoadIntent);
  }
});

function handleInvalidSessionResponse(data) {
  if (typeof data !== "undefined") return true;
  return false;
}
```

**Below is a mock JSFiddle of the scenario**
http://jsfiddle.net/ajxrw39m/3/

Comment: I still get the error, I have notice when I call frenchData from ajax, that is where the error occur

Comment: Provide your returned JSON from the AJAX call so that we have mock data to work with. Assistance can only be provided with a complete question. For instance, we have no idea what `account` and `getStudentRegRequirementsUrl` are supposed to be.

Comment: @Jseb updated and resolved based on some assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

When you're defining your viewmodel, `this` does not point to the newly created object, it points to whatever `this` is in the context you're creating it (probably `window`).

```js
var vm = {
  computedUsingThis: ko.computed(function() {
    return this;
  }, this)
}

console.log(
  vm.computedUsingThis() === vm,     // false
  vm.computedUsingThis() === window  // true
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

There are many ways to circumvent the issue. You can use a constructor function and the `new` keyword, or create a factory method for the viewmodel:

```js
const VM = () => {
  const a = ko.observable("a");
  const b = ko.observable("b");
  
  const ab = ko.pureComputed(
    () => a() + b()
  );
  
  return { a, b, ab };
}

const vm = VM();
vm.ab.subscribe(console.log);

setTimeout(
  () => {
    vm.a("A");
  },
  500
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```